# SSRS Report Server Issue User Accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I need to know if there is a way to change the configuration or a command to turn off/disable SSRS's integration to active directory accounts? I want to be able to add users on the Security tab that do not have a domain/computer login. I understand there is a CustomSecurity feature that you can enable (such as Forms Auth) but I don't want to utilize that whole process. I can access my reports view the following code:

```
    try
        {
            myReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            myReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.myReportViewerUser, Properties.Settings.Default.MyReportViewerPassword);
            HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();

            if (myResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
               this.iReports.Attributes["src"] = "http://myserver/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fUser+Reports%2fFacility+User%27s+Report";
            }
        }
```

I want to be able to create users in SSRS that correspond back to the Groups we have setup for our website (which is using FormsAuth) without creating a local logon or domain logon to the server machine. If I could do this it would isolate those logins from having any other access but to SSRS reports. The SSRS user created would correspond back to group thus specifying which reports that person would have access to run.

Has anyone worked on a similar situation? Please advise!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a thing as an "SSRS User." SSRS relies on other components to provide authentication. The CustomSecurity feature that you mention is the way to allow SSRS to authenticate against a provider other than Windows authentication.

(All due respect, but the statement "I understand there is a CustomSecurity feature that you can enable (such as Forms Auth) but I don't want to utilize that whole process." sounds a bit like "I know there's a way to do this, but I don't want to do it.")

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152825.aspx

> We recommend that you use Windows Authentication if at all possible. However, custom
>   authentication and authorization for Reporting Services may be appropriate in the 
>   following two cases:
>
> - You have an Internet or extranet application that cannot use Windows accounts.
> - You have custom-defined users and roles and need to provide a matching authorization scheme in Reporting Services.

Sorry I don't any better ideas...

Comment: Not really an answer. The first case is the reason for needing custom authentication. And enabling custom security the way that Microsoft's samples suggest to do it goes beyond the scope of what I need. So to say that "I know there is a way to do it, but I don't want to do it" is entirely incorrect. Their suggested way of implementation is not a one size fits all solution for my case.

Comment: If you don't use a security extension, then authentication will be provided by Windows (whether local user or domain.) If you need to _secure_ these reports by group, then your options are Windows Auth, a security extension, or handle your own security by creating a passthrough/wrapper web service and denying direct access to SSRS. (I think that would usually be more effort than creating a security extension.)

You could customize the reports based on a parameter providing the group, but that will not be as secure.